# How to set individual actions for array items?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a Wordpress Theme. It's a product showcase and my client needs me to add a function to represent visually the available colors for each product in a small "square" (div) with the `background-color` css property set to that colour.

In wordpress, I set each product post to have a custom meta field called "colorStock" where they can list the available colours in a comma separated list.

Something like this:

```
  rojo, azul, verde, amarillo
```

The list is in spanish and with colour names to make things much easier for the not-savvy users who will admin this page.

So, what I want to do is a function that will take these meta field values, put them in an array and perform different actions for each item.

Why? Well, because these values will be used to set the css `background-color` for little divs that will represent the colours.

So, what I need to do is to take each value, let's say "rojo", and make the function check if `rojo` is in a list of available ("supported") colours and output it as the valid color name or value related to `rojo`. (e.g. `"rojo = "red"` or  `"rojo" = "#f5f5f5"`).

So far I have this code:

```
function colorStock(){
    $postID = get_the_ID();
    $colorStock = get_post_meta($postID, 'colorStock', true); //Get Colours available
    $myArray = explode(',', $colorStock);
    //print_r($myArray); 
//echo $myArray;


     foreach ($myArray as $item){

        if (in_array("rojo", $item)) {
            echo "red";
        }
        if (in_array("verde", $item)) {
            echo "green";
        }
        if (in_array("azul", $item)) {
            echo "blue";
        }
        if (in_array("blanco", $item)) {
            echo "white";
        }
        if (in_array("negro", $item)) {
            echo "black";
        }
        if (in_array("amarillo", $item)) {
            echo "yellow";
        }
    }      
   }
```

I know that my `in_array` usage might not make sense at all, but the thing is that I need the function to take each array item, see if it matches any of the equivalences list items and then move to the next array item. So i will be able to output an individual `div` for each item, regardless if the admin listed 1 or 20 colours.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

By the way:  `$colorStock`outputs:
`rojo, verde, azul, amarillo`

and `$myArray`outputs:
`Array ( [0] => rojo [1] => verde [2] => azul )`

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, you simply need to remove the `foreach` loop. The `explode` statement creates an array, then just run through your `if(in_array(...))` statements ... no need to loop through the array ... or, you can keep the foreach and put a switch statement inside and just compare the value ...

Comment: When I do that, it only works with the first value of the list. Not with all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 foreach ($myArray as $item){ 

    $css_colors = array('verde' => '#008000', 
                            'rojo' => '#ff0000',
                            'azul' => '#0000ff',
                            'blanco' => '#ffffff',
                            'negro' => '#000000',
                            'amarillo' => '#ffff00');
    foreach ( $css_colors as $colorname => $value) {

     if ($colorname == $item) { 
            display_color($value);
    } 
   }
}  

function display_color($color)
{
    echo '<div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; background: '. $color . ';">&nbsp;</div>';
}
```

You can Try something like this you need to map the spanish valus to the right hex css values. I hope it helps! for a list of css color visit go here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Comment: Hello, Leandro! This solution works, but only for the first value (only a red square appears :/ )

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out! Your example has no spaces between commas and the next item's first character. And $colorStock value does :) Thank you! It was of great help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple map:

```
function colorStock() 
{
    $postID = get_the_ID();
    $colorStock = get_post_meta($postID, 'colorStock', true); //Get Colours available
    $colors = explode(',', $colorStock);

    $colorMap = array(
        'rojo'=>'red',
        'verde'=>'green'
    );

    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        if (isset($colorMap[$color])) {
            echo $colorMap[$color];
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hello webbiedave, this solution works only with the first value, I have three colours (rojo, verde, azul) and it it outputs red three times ( `redredred` )

Comment: Yeah! I figured it out. Your example has no spaces between commas and the next item's first character. And $colorStock value does :) Thank you! It was of great help!